# Remove records from a dataset?

Tags: r

I would like to know how I can remove from a dataset the records that have more than 5 null values in the columns that define them.I have thought that I can achieve this with the following code but I am not getting the result I should be getting:

```
cols_borrar <- which(colMeans(is.na(df)) >5)
```

Do you have any idea?

Thank you

Comment: It would be eaiser to help if you can provide a reproducible example, such as the output of `dput(head(df))`

Answer (score 0):

You're close! Use colSums() instead

```
filtered_df <- df[,which(colSums(is.na(df)) <= 5)]
```